# KDE vertical panel with 'windows can cover' option does not work

Tags: ubuntu, kde, kwin

I've done a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and added KDE.

I've setup the main panel (with taskbar, etc.) to be options: windows can cover.

Everything works as expected as long as the panel is horizontal. If I move it vertically, windows suddenly 'go under' it.

The problem occurs even for a new, empty panel as long as it's vertical.

Here's how it looks like. Added two panels: one horizontal (gray) at the top of the screen and one (also gray) on the right border. Changed 'window can cover' option on both and placed a terminal window over them. Only the horizontal one respects this setting:

[image]

Comment: I can remember that sort of glitch but under a rather old version of kde-plasma. Could you please provide infos regarding versions of the kde-plasma / kde-frameworks / Qt packages and video backend (X11/Wayland) (all infos visible via the kde info center)

Comment: @MC68020: 
plazma: 5.24.7, 
kde: 5.92.0, 
qt: 5.15.3, 
kernel: 6.2.0-36, 
X11

Comment: @MC68020 I (kind of) fixed that by setting up a window rule for the vertical panel. It still will bring up the menu above a window when I click on it but it's close enough...